# After replace firewalld with iptables，the docker container is missing

Tags: docker

[image]

I create the containers when I use `firewalld`. After I change the `firewalld` to `iptables`,

I can find container directory and volume folder, but I can't see when I type docker `ps -a`. When I type network `docker network ls`, I lose my custom bridge network.

So what can I do to get them back?

Comment: My Version:
Docker version 17.09.1-ce
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: I found my docker/daemon.json configuration changed .But I don't know why it was changed